# Transforming a python list to a php array with brackets

Tags: python, list, python-requests

I am trying to post a request to an API. Unfortunately, they don't accept Python lists.
The API wants an array of arrays. You can look it up [here](https://filecrypt.cc/docs/index.htm#api-Container-edit).

For example this does not work:

```py
data={
"mirror_1":[["http://example1.link/","http://example2.link/"]]
}
```

Neither does this:

```py
data={
"mirror_1":["http://example1.link/","http://example2.link/"]
}
```

Both would create a empty folder without the links.

But this does work:

```py
data={
"mirror_1[0][0]":"http://example1.link/",
"mirror_1[0][1]":"http://example2.link/"
}
```

Is there a way to automatically transform a list into the working ones?
Unfortunately, I don't know much about PHP and their arrays.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the desired final format of these?

Comment: Thats just a normal dictionary?

Comment: Encode the data to json format and decode it in php

Comment: But what if they can't use php?

Comment: Isn't that what the question is about?

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup - They're posting to an api, it doesn't matter what language thats in

Comment: @Andreas, they are not using php, they are using python. Encoding json in python and decoding it in php doesn't seem like a good option since it would require running php as well as python.

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup then why is the question tagged PHP and the last section of the code states: *Is there a way to automatically transform an list into the working ones? Unfortunately I don't know much about PHP and their arrays.*

Comment: @Tammys Head do you want to use php to send the request or do you want to do that in python?

Comment: @Andreas the question is also tagged "python-requests". It seems like Tammys Head wants to make the request in python

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup I wanna use it in Python. Like i said, I never used php before. But if it would require me to install php, that wouldn't be a problem I think.

Comment: I added the php tag because of the API which is written in PHP. But I removed it now, sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, if you can use php for everything, that would make things easier. If you are going to use php and python, then you take your python list, and convert it to json and write it to a file.

```
file = open("thejson.json", "w")
towrite = json.dumps(thelist)
file.write(towrite)
file.close()
```

Then in php you open the file and convert it to an array

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("thejson.json");
$arr = json_decode($json_string, true);
```

And $arr is your php array.

Per the link you gave:

```
<?php
define('YES', 1);
define('NO', 0);
$USE_SSL      = true;
$api_key      = "MY_FILECRYPT_API_KEY";
$name         = "My Testfolder";
$group        = MyGroupID;
$container_id = MyContainerId;
// Here you grab the json from the file and convert it to an array

$json_string = file_get_contents("thejson.json");
$arr = json_decode($json_string, true);

$mirror_1 = $arr

// --------------------------
$postdata = http_build_query(array(
  "fn"          => "containerV2",
  "sub"         => "editV2",
  "container_id"=> $container_id,
  "api_key"     => $api_key,
  "name"        => $name,
  "mirror_1"    => $mirror_1,
  "captcha"     => YES,
  "allow_cnl"   => YES,
  "allow_dlc"   => YES,
  "allow_links" => NO,
  "group"       => $group
));
$opts     = array('http' => array(
  "method"  => "POST",
  "header"  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "content" => $postdata
));
$context  = stream_context_edit($opts);
$result   = file_get_contents('http'.(($USE_SSL)?'s':'').'://www.filecrypt.cc/api.php', false, $context);
if(!$result) {
  throw new Exception("filecrypt.cc api down");
} else {
  $json = json_decode($result);
  echo "editd container: ".$json->container->link;
}
?>
```

This should work, but you would have to either install php or run it on a php server.

So you would be making the request in php.

For more info on php here is a link: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/

This guide is a good php reference to look at if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm sure it'll work out this way ^^